# Was Windows 98 the last Windows that allows you to install multiple Windows on the same partition?

Tags: windows

Was Windows 98 the last Windows that allows you to install multiple Windows on the same partition?

i.e. one partition and you could have for example, a directory `c:\windows1` and `c:\windows2`

Comment: I'm vaguely sure I had Windows 98 in C:\WINDOWS and Windows 2000 in C:\WINNT on the same partition in the past...

Answer (score 1):

Windows 98 was the last system I know of where you could copy the CAB files from the CD to your computer and install Windows 98 from the CAB files. I did this several times.

It makes sense that you could work from two different CAB file setups and get two Windows 98 systems running.

Most people would use the same Windows 98 license and it did not check.

The next major user system after Windows 98 was Windows XP and starting the SP2, XP did check and if you have two concurrent Windows XP systems running on the same computer, it would complain and one system would not run.

There were no CAB files to set up in XP like Windows 98.

So the entire setup changed with XP and all operating systems forward.

So I am fairly sure Windows 98 was the last system where you could put two Windows 98 installs on the same partition. It could also be Windows ME but that is something I never used or saw.

Comment: Windows ME was part of the Window 9x series and came out before XP. It used the same installer as 98 and also used CAB files. While I can't say for certain that you could install multiple copies of ME on the same partition as I never tried it... your answer lacks any reasoning as to why ME would be unable to. Perhaps you could expand on this?

Comment: I never used ME and never saw too many ME systems. You could be correct, but certainly by XP you could not put two XP systems on the same partition.

Comment: ME was installed on the majority of new systems between September 2000 and October 2001. While this is a short run for an MS operating system... many, many computers were built in that time with ME installed. As a computer technician of 25 years, I remember a period well into the '00s where Windows ME computers were still quite common. It's also worth noting the Windows 2000 came out shortly before Windows ME and was targeted at business users... and could not be installed twice on the same partition. Though Windows NT3.0 and 
NT4.0 predate even Windows 98.